# How to make process to do some action upon user request in Python?

Tags: python

I somehow confused about how it can be implemented. Many applications provide ability for user to initiate some action inside them without restarting the application. To be more clear "/etc/init.d/apache2 reload" will force Apache process to reload its configuration files without restarting. How would I go to implement same approach for my Python application?

Comment: It is a broad question. Reloading a config in-process in one feature. Providing a mechanism of controlling the process behavior from the outside is a different thing. Where you'd like to focus?

Comment: @pajton, I am looking for more conceptual answer. F.e. my guess about one of ways to implement that is to actually start new process, locate original process from it, send it a signal via kill -USR1 $PID and wait for an output. But then I am stuck with limited number of signals. On the other hand I am unsure that this is how such things are implemented, and this is why I ask community for their knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reset your application in python by defining a method to do so:

```
import sys
import os
def restart_program():
    python = sys.executable
    os.execl(python, python, * sys.argv)
```

And then let the user initiate this code upon request:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    answer = raw_input("Do you want to restart this program ? ")
    if answer == "yes":
        restart_program()
```

This code was taken from [here](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/260268/restart-your-python-program). Apache resets upon command because the program was written to accept such a command, as python is a language in which you create a program, you need to implement this functionality.

If you want to just reset some variables then you could do something like:

```
def reset_var():
    global var1
    global var2
    var1 = 0
    var2 = 0
```

Reload a file:

```
file = open('words.txt', 'r')

def reloadfile():
    file.close()
    file = open('words.txt', 'r')
```

Comment: This will actually restart the program. Maybe there are some heavy duty calculations going on or someone is connected to the app through socket server and of course we do not want to break all processes in the mid air.

Comment: then define a method to do that: `def reset_var (): global var1; global var2; var1 = 0; var2 = 0`

Answer (score 0):

The /etc/init.d/ directory contains a series of scripts that manage services. You can create a new script in this directory to allow you to start/stop/restart any program you write. The commands for starting and stopping go into this directory, not into your program. For example, to stop services, many of these scripts just call the 'kill' or 'killall' commands.

Here are some links that describe the directory and how to create your own scripts for it:

http://www.ghacks.net/2009/04/04/get-to-know-linux-the-etcinitd-directory/
http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/HighQuality-Apps-HOWTO/boot.html